# Simple Ratios Question involving Currency

Tags: ratio, gre-exam

> In nation Z, 10 terble coins equal 1 galok.  In nation Y, 6 barbar coins equal 1 murb. If a galok is worth 40% more than a murb, what is the raio of the value of 1 terble coin to the value of 1 barbar coin?

I derived the following equalities:

- 10 terbles = 1 galok
- 1 galok = 1.4 murbs
- 1 murb = 6 barbars

I'm getting two different solutions depending on my approach.

***Approach 1***

Compute the number of barbars for a single terble coin:

$1\,terble  \times\,\frac{1\,galok}{10\,terble} \times\,\frac{1.4\,murbs}{1\,galok}\times\,\frac{6\,barbars}{1\,murb} = \frac{21}{25}\, barbars.$

Since the question is asking for the fraction $\frac{terbles}{barbars}$.  So,

$\frac{1\,terble}{\frac{21}{25}\,barbars} = \frac{25\, terbles}{21\,barbars}.$

***Approach 2***

Compute terbles and barbars in terms of a third unit, such as murbs, and form a ratio in that unit.

$1\,terble \times\frac{1\,galok}{10\,terble} \times\,\frac{1.4\,murbs}{1\,galok} = \frac{14}{100}\,murbs$

$1\,barbar\times\frac{1\,murb}{6\,barbars} = \frac{1}{6}\,murbs$

$\frac{1\,terble}{1\,barbar} = \frac{\frac{14}{100}\,murbs}{\frac{1}{6}\,murbs} = \frac{21\,terbles}{25\,barbars}$

The book uses Approach 2, but I'm stumped on why Approach 1 is producing an incorrect result.

Comment: You do know that there are much easier approaches right

Comment: If $x=\frac ab y$ then what is $\frac xy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the raio of the value of 1 terble coin to the value of 1 barbar coin?

You have $1 \mathsf{terble} = \frac{21}{25}\mathsf{barbar}$ which is okay. $\color{darkgreen}\checkmark$  Then you go all awry.   You just needed to divide both side by $\color{navy}{1}$ barbar.

The ratio required is clearly a dimensionless number: $\dfrac{1\mathsf{terble}}{1\mathsf{barbar}}=\dfrac {21}{25}$

Comment: Just to clarify, it would be incorrect to say:
(number of treble coins) : (number of barber coins) = 21 : 25.

Instead it's (the value of 1 treble coin) : (value of 1 barber coin) = 21 : 25.

Comment: @shj Yes, exactly.